# Do you know of any web application code generation tools?

Tags: web-services, frontend, code-generation, backend, backendless

I stumbled upon https://tomassetti.me/code-generation/ which is a list of code generation tools and I was wondering if there were any tools that generate backend or frontend code based on the web app's models(schema).

Answer (score 2):

You can try **Telosys** http://www.telosys.org/ this code generator is often used to create web application (MVC or REST) for any kind of languages/frameworks.

Code generation can be achieved with the command line tool or with an Eclipse Plugin.

This article https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/ is a good introduction for this tool.

Here's a short video demonstrating the main steps of the code generation with the CLI tool : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJQixseAsCg